# Removing the duplicates from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Duplicate values are being storing into an array of object

Based on the given `userID` need to out the duplicate `userId`, 
if it exist do nothing, else push that `userId`into the teamSocketsList array

But with the below piece of code duplicate values are being stored into an array teamSocketsList

```
var  TeamUser = {
    userId : userID,
    socketId : socket.id
}

var i = $.inArray( userID, teamSocketsList ); 
if(i == -1){
    teamSocketsList.push(TeamUser);
}else{
        teamSocketsList = jQuery.grep(teamSocketsList, function(value) {
        return value != userID;
    });
}
```

**Actual Result:**

```
[
    {"userId":1,"socketId":"M8xzpi3O0cMHXe-dAAAK"},
    {"userId":1,"socketId":"ZIbgYMLOda_R5QqvAAAN"},
    {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"},
    {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"}
]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[
    {"userId":1,"socketId":"M8xzpi3O0cMHXe-dAAAK"},
    {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"},
]
```

---

**Edit:**

Here I'm expecting `userID` to be pushed in to an array `teamSocketsList` based on the condition, if at all the given `userID` matches in the present list should return false or do nothing. Otherwise, (iff, it's not at all included then) store it into an array with the auto-generated `socketId` value

The logic which I had tried to implement was to check whether if that array is empty or not and then, traverse all the elements in the array list so that whenever `userID` were given as an input it must check the condition and then push that element.

Based on the present answers put up, it'll store the duplicate values and then sort it on and assign it back to `teamSocketsList`, that's fine.

Comment: post your input

Comment: `{"userId":1,"socketId":"M8xzpi3O0cMHXe-dAAAK"}` is different from `{"userId":1,"socketId":"ZIbgYMLOda_R5QqvAAAN"}`. What is the criteria for keeping the first instead of the next one?

Comment: Inputs are from the actual results shown @KunalMukherjee

Comment: For particular `userId` only one unique `socketId` should be assigned @briosheje

Comment: @Nishanthॐ I got that, but **how** do you know that the socket id is the first one? it may get inconsistent.

Comment: Based on logging on to the team page only one unique `socketId` will be assigned for each user @briosheje

Comment: @Nishanthॐ so the input is invalid?

Comment: No each time when user logs or refreshes the page generates unique ID that should be stored into an array so as to confirm that user is alive. For more info refer to socket.js. As I'm trying to get the output value for userid logged on @briosheje

Comment: `array.filter(function (obj) { return !this[obj.userId] && (this[obj.userId] = true); }, {})`

Comment: Note that `inArray` won't match a numeric value, held in a variable called `userId`, with an object with a property named `userId` holding the same value.

Comment: How should need to match the element of `userId` with `userID` traversing whole elements in an array. If you could answer edit my question mentioning your name with an answer, so that other readers would benefit a lot. Should we need to use ECMAScript and thank you for reopening @traktor53

Answer (score 0):

Along with already mentioned values/reduce, you can take advantage of [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const myArray = [
    {"userId":1,"socketId":"M8xzpi3O0cMHXe-dAAAK"},
    {"userId":1,"socketId":"ZIbgYMLOda_R5QqvAAAN"},
    {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"},
    {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"}
]

const unique = (arr, key) => {
   const keys = new Set();
   return arr.filter(el => !keys.has(el[key]) && keys.add(el[key]));
 };

console.log(unique(myArray, "userId"));
```

In opposition to other response I can point out that with this method is easier to change array and key without adding code.

Answer (score -1):

use `reduce` along with `Object.values`. create an object whose keys are `userId`. If the key does not exist, create the key and then use `Object.values` to get the required ouput.

```js
const input = [
    {"userId":1,"socketId":"M8xzpi3O0cMHXe-dAAAK"},
    {"userId":1,"socketId":"ZIbgYMLOda_R5QqvAAAN"},
    {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"},
    {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"}
];

const output = Object.values(input.reduce((accu, {userId, socketId}) => {
    if(!accu[userId]) accu[userId] = {userId, socketId};
    return accu;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this function where you pass in your array and the key to get your result

```js
        const convertArrayToObjecByID = ({ array, key }) =>
          array.reduce((obj, item) => {
                return { ...obj, [item[key]]: item };
              }, {})

        const input = [
            {"userId":1,"socketId":"M8xzpi3O0cMHXe-dAAAK"},
            {"userId":1,"socketId":"ZIbgYMLOda_R5QqvAAAN"},
            {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"},
            {"userId":9,"socketId":"XAf1cepsLv-KDpn3AAAQ"}
        ]
        const myObject = convertArrayToObjecByID({ array:input, key:'userId' })
console.log({myObject})
//then if you want it as an array 
    console.log(Object.keys(myObject).map(item => myObject[item]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store your data in the object (key-value pair) and avoid adding duplicate data.
For example:

```
var teamSocketsList = {};

var TeamUser = {
    userId : userID,
    socketId : socket.id
}

teamSocketsList[TeamUser.userId] = TeamUser;
```

Then if you are adding new user to teamSocketsList, you can easily (without iterating through all elements in the array) check if there are teamUser with that id.

```
if(teamSocketsList[TeamUser.userId]) // team user exists in the list
```

Comment: Although it does not try to answer to OP question I have to point out that this is exactly the way I would implement it to solve the issue before it's generated

Comment: That would be resulting in storing inconsistent data structure with Team Socket List: [null,{"userId":1,"socketId":"cIoxHto6yK7vw_WeAAAM"},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"userId":9,"socketId":"FBVi7peHCrL6r4YcAAAO"}] @MosèRaguzzini

Comment: when retrieving socket list it wil suffice to apply a simple filter: [].filter(o => o) to get rid of null values.

Comment: I'm surprised that after getting rid of null values still stores the duplicate data `Team Socket List: [{"userId":9,"socketId":"iYdg8Hpq__dV-tyFAAAJ"},{"userId":1,"socketId":"gQQ247cGqcnFOaX7AAAN"},{"userId":9,"socketId":"vYD0A5UzTCwfFHtgAAAL"},{"userId":9,"socketId":"vYD0A5UzTCwfFHtgAAAL"}]` @MosèRaguzzini

Comment: @Nishanthॐ it means that the array already held those values.